Facing error in yarn install for isolated-vm on macOS
Trying to build Backstage App on my MacOS, one of its pre requisites is Yarn , But i am unsuccessful in trying to install it. Please help
I am encountering an error when running yarn install for a project on my macOS system. The error seems to be related to the isolated-vm package and involves node-gyp failing to build the module. Below is the error message I receive:
I also tried removing node modules and lock file using rm -r node_modules && rm yarn.lock && yarn install but it's still failing.
System Details:

Operating System: macOS

Node.js Version: 18.20.4

Architecture: arm64


error /Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/isolated-vm: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: prebuild-install || (node-gyp rebuild --release -j max && node-gyp clean)
Arguments:
Directory: /Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/isolated-vm
Output:
prebuild-install warn install No prebuilt binaries found (target=18.20.4 runtime=node arch=arm64 libc= platform=darwin)
gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
gyp info using node-gyp@10.2.0
gyp info using node@18.20.4 | darwin | arm64
gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.12 found at "/Users/vidhiyadav/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3"

gyp info spawn /Users/vidhiyadav/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3
gyp info spawn args \[
gyp info spawn args '/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-f',
gyp info spawn args 'make',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/isolated-vm/build/config.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-I',
gyp info spawn args '/Users/vidhiyadav/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.20.4/include/node/common.gypi',
gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/vidhiyadav/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.20.4',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/vidhiyadav/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.20.4/\<(target_arch)/node.lib',
gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/isolated-vm',
gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
gyp info spawn args 'build',
gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
gyp info spawn args \]
No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLILeo' found at '/'.

No receipt for 'com.apple.pkg.DeveloperToolsCLI' found at '/'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1501, in XcodeVersion
version_list = GetStdoutQuiet(\["xcodebuild", "-version"\]).splitlines()
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1562, in GetStdoutQuiet
raise GypError("Error %d running %s" % (job.returncode, cmdlist\[0\]))
gyp.common.GypError: Error 1 running xcodebuild

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py", line 45, in \<module\>
sys.exit(gyp.script_main())
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 688, in script_main
return main(sys.argv\[1:\])
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 680, in main
return gyp_main(args)
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/__init__.py", line 665, in gyp_main
generator.GenerateOutput(flat_list, targets, data, params)
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 2682, in GenerateOutput
writer.Write(
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 912, in Write
self.WriteCopies(spec\["copies"\], extra_outputs, part_of_all)
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 1308, in WriteCopies
env = self.GetSortedXcodeEnv()
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/generator/make.py", line 2279, in GetSortedXcodeEnv
return gyp.xcode_emulation.GetSortedXcodeEnv(
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1887, in GetSortedXcodeEnv
env = \_GetXcodeEnv(
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1742, in \_GetXcodeEnv
"XCODE_VERSION_ACTUAL": XcodeVersion()\[0\],
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1512, in XcodeVersion
version = CLTVersion()  # macOS Catalina returns 11.0.0.0.1.1567737322
File "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/pylib/gyp/xcode_emulation.py", line 1550, in CLTVersion
return re.search(regex, output).groupdict()\["version"\]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groupdict'
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.\<anonymous\> (/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:317:18)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:517:28)
gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.\_handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:292:12)
gyp ERR! System Darwin 23.5.0
gyp ERR! command "/Users/vidhiyadav/.nvm/versions/node/v18.20.4/bin/node" "/Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/.bin/node-gyp" "rebuild" "--release" "-j" "max"
gyp ERR! cwd /Users/vidhiyadav/Desktop/vidhi-devops/node_modules/isolated-vm


Getting this same error today, four months later with isolated_vm, attempting to build a system called formio.

UPDATE: Look at the comments by the author of isolated-vm here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/isolated-vm#frequently-asked-question he is saying to look at the version of the compiler.
But! He is also saying the project is in maintenance mode and no new features are being added.

UPDATE: An issue has been opened: https://github.com/formio/formio/issues/1832 to tackle this build problem, perhaps that can help here as well.
